# Does anyone recall this linear algebra survey of results?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I'm not sure if math stackexchange is the appropriate place for this, but I am looking for a paper that consisted of results in linear algebra, since I've lost the pdf of it and can't recall the author.

It was a survey of results, with either proofs or published references, in the field of finite dimensional linear algebra. It assumed familiarity with the subject, but not expert knowledge, and was motivated as a presentation of nontrivial results that deserve to be known more broadly.

There were lots of results proved within, but I can only recall one specifically, which hopefully is obscure enough to track down the paper. The result was (if I recall correctly) that a linear operator is similar to its inverse if and only if it is the product of two involutions.

Hopefully someone recognises something here, as it was a great reference for more advanced aspects of finite dimensional linear algebra.

Comment: https://core.ac.uk/reader/82344482
here is a paper where that result is cited

Comment: http://culturagalega.gal/album/docs/textos_214_18.pdf and this is the original paper where it is proved

Comment: @Exodd I think you should make that an answer

Comment: Excellent! I’ll try work back from that to find the survey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the book, its Problems and Theorems in Linear Algebra, by V. Prasolov.

Answer (score 3):

[core.ac.uk/reader/82344482](http://core.ac.uk/reader/82344482) 
Here the result is cited. Following the reference, you find
[culturagalega.gal/album/docs/textos_214_18.pdf](http://culturagalega.gal/album/docs/textos_214_18.pdf) 
that is the original paper where it is proved.

I don't know if one of those is the paper you were  looking for, but you can for example look for papers citing one of those and then go down the white rabbit's hole.